# "...is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: variables, cmd, path, environment

I know that there's already this topic, but, the reason why I'm writing this is those other topics...

I run into a problem with GIT command "clone". CMD throw an error that said "clone is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.", so naturally I searched the error, and found some solutions here, and I did couple of them (since nothign worked), and now nothing works. I can't even start SASS, since it throws the same error: "sass is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

So, what should I do?

Here's a SS of my path variables:
[image]

[image]

I'm sure I made it worse...but now, I don't know what to do, except to reinstall windows.
Bare in mind that I read the obvious solutions here, and it didn't work, or I didn't do it correctly.....but something's not right :/

Comment: I created the PATH in a upper table, because somebody said to do that, so I did it... 
As far as PATHEXT goes, that was there from the beginning. I read the link you gave me, but I don't quit get it. 

I understand that the path is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Now when I think of it, there was one PATH var in a upper table also... I just changed it.

Comment: I'm very close to installing a windows again, cause it seems that I messed this up quit good :D

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by reinstalling windows. I didn't wan't to make it even worse. So... This is one of the solutions, if you can't get around all the PATHS and variables thing.. :)